# Components on top of components block the mouse position

Tags: delphi

My Delphi 7 app has two TPageControls with a TSplitter between them. On each TPageControl are two TTabSheets. One each TTabSheet is a TWebBrowser.  Got the picture?

The problem with this component arrangement is that it is impossible to track the location of the mouse since the TWebBrowser does not have a OnMouseMove event and the TForm's OnMouseMove event is never triggered under this pile of ClientAligned components.

What I need to know is the XY position of the mouse, relative to the app's form, at all times. IOW, I need to know when the mouse moved, and when it does, a function that would:

```
GetMouseLocationNow(var X, Y : Integer);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need that coordinate tracking ? What is the content you're showing in those browsers ? I'm asking to suggest you better way than some periodical asking for coordinates whose might not even match to the displayed web browser's content because of scroll offset for instance.

Comment: I need to know when to set the focus on the TWebBrowser that is under the mouse. This way the TWebBrowser contents will scroll when the user uses the mouse wheel. Since there will always be two TWebBrowsers visible at all times, I need some way to know which TWebBrowser to set the focus on. I can only do that by tracking the mouse position.

Comment: If your aim is to have a *scroll the control under the mouse* feature, I think that you need to globally catch the mouse scroll event and ask which control is under the cursor rather than mouse move tracking.

Comment: Your suggestion is interesting, but I wonder if catching the mouse scroll event would be too late, seeing how one still has to then focus the TWebBrowser AFTER the scrolling event has been triggered.

Comment: No, you wouldn't set the focus. You would just dispatch the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message to the control under the cursor. I've seen this feature implemented only without stealing focus. It's quite annoying for the users to steal the focus of the control when they just hover the mouse and scroll the wheel. But never mind. Good luck anyway! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track mouse move application-wide, you have to track `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message. You can use `TApplicationEvents` component for that. So, drop `TApplicationEvents` on form, and process `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in `OnMessage` event. Low order word in `LParam` specifies `X` coordinate of the cursor (relative to the window that the message is posted to), and high order word `Y` coordinate.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ApplicationEventsMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEMOVE then begin
    Pt := Point(WORD(Msg.lParam), HiWord(Msg.lParam));
    windows.ClientToScreen(Msg.hwnd, Pt);
    windows.ScreenToClient(Handle, Pt);
    MouseMoved(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.MouseMoved(const AX, AY: Integer);
begin
  // do the work here
end;
```

Comment: See also [`ScreenToClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ScreenToClient) and [`PtInRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162882.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but your code doesn't tell me when the mouse has moved.  With the component layout that I described above, I don't know that the mouse has moved. I am not going to call the function until I know that the mouse has moved.

Comment: Thanks @RobKennedy, didn't know about that! I edited the function above. user1527613, that's not what you asked in original question. Maybe you could explicitly handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.

Comment: @user1527613, I edited the answer above to include `WM_MOUSEMOVE` tracking.

Comment: LOWORD and HIWORD are not valid functions in Delphi 7.  I also should have clarified that I need the XY position relative to the Client area of the TForm.

Comment: @user - HiWord is valid, and for LoWord cast it to a word. You can add a test for if the message is for the browser control, but I think the answer is fine otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, however, Word and HiWord are not giving me the XY values relative to the TForm.  Instead, they are giving me values relative to the component the mouse is hovering over.  IOW, hovering over a TButton centered on a 30 pixel tall TPanel whose Align := alBottom on a 800 pixel high TForm will return a Y value in the range of 5 to 25, rather than 770 to 800.

Comment: @user - I'm sure you can figure out how to get what you want. You have the window handle that the message is posted to in `Msg.hwnd`, you also have `ClientToScreen`, `ScreenToClient` etc..

Comment: ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient will not give me a point relative to the TForm, or even to the entire screen, when used with WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: @user - Here you go, I've modified the answer. As you can see it's using Msg.hwnd, ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient.

Comment: I figured it out. One cannot use the LoWord and HiWord values from the message. Instead, one has to use ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).

Comment: @user - Did you read my last comment and the modified answer yet?

Comment: I did, however I had come up with my ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos) solution while you were typing your last comment.

Comment: @user - Well, your assertion that *"one cannot use the LoWord and HiWord"* is incorrect, I meant the note that by pointing to the modification. Your solution will of course work BTW, but the message already comes with coordinates - no need to query them again.